# How to run a powershell script from neko haxe?

Tags: powershell, haxe, neko

I need to run a powershell script from haxe code and return data. I will use this data in my code.

How I can do this?

Comment: briantist, I don`t know what to googled, I tried "haxe neko powershell", "neko haxe run powershell script", "haxe run powershell" - empty. How I can find answer to my question?

Comment: You can begin by trying to do it yourself, and then searching for the specific problems you have, and then if you don't find answers you can post a question here asking about them. But you have not shown any effort; you're just asking us to do all the research for you and give you an answer, and that isn't how this site works. See [ask] and then try providing a [mcve].

Comment: This is not a weird question if you dont know what to search. These typical default answers (what have you tried) don't help much too, how can you even provide a minimal example of stuff you dont even know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a `sys.io.Process` from Neko.

Check out the api docs
http://api.haxe.org/sys/io/Process.html

To see an example of how to use it, check this
http://code.haxe.org/category/macros/add-git-commit-hash-in-build.html

In your case it would look like this

```
var process = new sys.io.Process('powershell', ['any parameters']);
```

Note: I'm not sure if you really need powershell since you can execute stuff commandline with this.

I hope this helps!